# How to use multiple nested ternary operators to return a value

Tags: c#, comparison, operators

I am looking at using a multiple nested ternary operators. I have 3 values I want to compare. All 3 are integers. For example:

```
val1
val2
threshold
```

From all this I want a result of `1` or `0`.

So, if I was to do this using `if-else` statements, my logic will look like this:

```
if (val1 - val2 > threshold)
{
    result = 1;
}
else if (val2 - val1 > threshold)
{
    result = 1;
}
```

So far I have this:

```
int d = (alpha < 0 ? -alpha : alpha) > threshold ? (alpha < 0 ? -alpha : alpha) : 1;
```

which, although it compiles, does not give me the same result...

Comment: This is not very readable. Don't do that unless required by some very strong evil forces.

Comment: @PatriceGahide lol, yes I know but speed is of the essence here and I wanted to see what was quickest :)

Comment: C# is not designed for such tricks. You won't see any speed difference in this particular case because the resulting IL will hardly be different. Let the compiler do his own optimizations, he's better than you at this game. Consider optimizations (and micro-optimizations) only when you spot an inefficient method that slows down your application below an acceptable limit.

Comment: HI, thanks for that info.  That is the issue though as using that routine slows my app down because of the amount of times I am calling it..

Comment: OK. Well ternary operators won't help you here ;) Maybe you could post some code in another question to see if we can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
result = (val1 - val2 > thresold) ? 1 : (val2-val1 > thresold) ? 1 : 0;
```

Or

```
result = (val1 - val2 > thresold) || (val2-val1 > thresold) ? 1 : 0;
```

Or

```
result = Math.Abs(val1 - val2) > thresold ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks all your examples.  Would you know what is more memory efficient?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = val1 - val2 > threshold ? 1 : val2 - val1 > threshold ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not this:

```
int d = (val1 - val2 > threshold) || (val2 - val1 > threshold) ? 1 : 0;
```

However, consider carefully if this is more readable than the `if` statements. Indescriminate use of the `?:` operator can make it more difficult to read and comprehend code.